# Predicate to prove goals on another kb_store

Tags: erlog

I've been looking to implement a built-in predicate that would permit me to prove a goal on another Kb_store.

ex :

```
{ok, Db1} = erlog:new(<<"Db1Handle">>),
{ok, Db2} = erlog:new(<<"Db2Handle">>),

erlog:prove({assert, {tasty, beer}}, <<"Db1Handle">>).

erlog:prove({prove_external, <<"Db1Handle">>, {tasty, {'X'}}},<<"Db2Handle">>).   %% Call tasty predicate on Db1 from Db2
> {succeed, [{'X',beer}]}
```

I've made my own Db handler which is working fine, with those handles, that's ok.

but I'm having serious difficulties to get this : **prove_external(DbHandle, ExternalGoal)** goal working.

I've written a built-in predicate which changes the Db ref from the #db record into the erlog state, before calling prove_goal on the external goal :

```
prove_external({_Atom, ExternalKb, Goal}, Next0, #est{bs = Bs} = St) ->
  OldDb = St#est.db,
  NewDb = OldDb#db{ref = ExternalKb},
  case erlog_int:prove_goal({call,Goal}, [], St#est{db = NewDb}) of
    {succeed, NewState} ->
      erlog_int:prove_body(Next0, NewState#est{db = OldDb});
    {fail, NewState} ->
      erlog_int:fail(NewState#est{db = OldDb});
    Else2 ->
      erlog_int:fail(St)
  end.
```

The external Goal is then correctly proved, But the following clauses to the prove_external will stay on the external Kb instead of swapping back to original Kb.

I've read : http://rvirding.blogspot.ro/2009/03/backtracking-in-erlang-part-1-control.html which illustrates the working principle but I'am getting lost into the details of implementation. I know I have to update CPS in some way, but I'm still confused on how to do this.

Please, could someone whisper me the issue or a way to proceed for this prove_external to work, that would help me a lot.

Thanks, 
Yan.